# Django: Add new field in Data View

Tags: python, django

All hello! I  use get _ context _ data

```
class YourDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = "quizli"
    model = Quizli

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):       
        context = super(YourDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["ll"]  = 33
        return context

..................................
......................................

url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', YourDetailView.as_view(
                template_name="quiz.html")),
```

in templates:

```
len: <div class="quest">{{ object.ll}}</div>
```

Instead of `33`, returns "" Please, help

Answer (score 1):

The context variable is named `ll`, not `object.ll`. Therefore, try:

```
<div class="quest">{{ ll }}</div>
```